# Create custom functions in sqlite3 in node js

Tags: node.js, sqlite

How do I create functions in sqlite3 in nodeJS?

I want to create my own custom function such as levenshtein functions and others, how can I do so in nodeJS environment?

Comment: Read the documentation for the sqlite bindings you're using to see how, assuming it's something they support.